# Interpreting incremental dumps of Wikidata

Tags: dataset, linked-data, wikidata

I'm looking into [incremental dumps of Wikidata](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/incr/wikidatawiki/). 
I found these files are interesting.

What kind of data is stored in each different two files, wikidatawiki-20160802-pages-meta-hist-incr.xml.bz2 and wikidatawiki-20160802-stubs-meta-hist-incr.xml.gz under [the directory](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/incr/wikidatawiki/20160802/)?

In each file, how data is organized?

In addition, how can change of content described in JSON as folloows be interpreted?

```
{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;item&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;Q25659310&quot;,&quot;labels&quot;:{&quot;mi&quot;:{&quot;language&quot;:&quot;mi&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;H\u0113nare Matua&quot;}},&quot;descriptions&quot;:[],&quot;aliases&quot;:[],&quot;claims&quot;:[],&quot;sitelinks&quot;:{&quot;miwiki&quot;:{&quot;site&quot;:&quot;miwiki&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;H\u0113nare Matua&quot;,&quot;badges&quot;:[]}}}
```

Is there any page to give some tips?